# Bit Commitment - from any One Way Permutations

Tags: protocol-design, one-way-function, commitments

In the [Wiki Page on Commitments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#Construction), it is given that a commitment scheme may be `perfectly binding` **or** `perfectly concealing` but **not both**.

But in the following section about [Bit-commitment from any one-way permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme#Bit-commitment_from_any_one-way_permutation), they mention that "This scheme is concealing..." and  "Perfect binding follows..."

It does seem like this commitment scheme is both `binding` and `concealing`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is "computationally" concealing --- that is it conceals only to a computationally bounded adversary. Note that computationally hiding, perfectly binding and computationally binding, perfectly hiding commitment schemes are, both, possible.